# The output of reduce function in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am confused by what the output of `reduce` should be in MapReduce.

According to the original Jeff Dean and Sanjay Ghemawat [paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) Section 2.2, it should be

```
reduce (k2,list(v2)) → list(v2)
```

But according to the [Hadoop tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html) Section `Inputs and Outputs`, and the [oreilly book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hadoop-the-definitive/9781449398644/ch07.html) it is a list of `(K3, V3)`

So what's the difference and are they essentially the same thing or not?

Comment: Note: Your hadoop tutorial link is several years old, and not the latest version

Answer (score 0):

in fact,
output of a mapreduce job is some files, that each one is generated by a reducer, and each generated file is a list of (key, value) pairs that we made them in reduce(...) function by calling context,write(...)

for more reminding, we define type of these key and value objects before executing the job by calling

`job.setOutputKeyClass(class...);`

`job.setOutputValueClass(class...);`